# Unmarshal blank strings to null with BeanIO

Tags: java, bean-io

[BeanIO reference guide](http://www.beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#FixedLengthFields) states that for a fixed-length stream:

> if required is set to false, spaces are unmarshalled to a null field value regardless of the padding character.

So if I understand this sentence correctly, it means that the test below should pass for this pojo:

```
@Record
public class Pojo {

    @Field(length = 5, required = false)
    String field;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

The test:

```
@Test
public void test(){

    StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
    factory.define(new StreamBuilder("pojo")
    .format("fixedlength")
    .addRecord(Pojo.class));

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = factory.createUnmarshaller("pojo");

    Pojo pojo = (Pojo) unmarshaller.unmarshal("     "); // 5 spaces
    assertNull(pojo.field);

}
```

But it fails, the 5 spaces are unmarshalled as an empty string. What am I missing? How can I unmarshal spaces to a null String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I managed this problem with the use of a [type handler](http://www.beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#CustomTypeHandlers) based on [StringTypeHandler](http://beanio.org/2.0/docs/api/org/beanio/types/StringTypeHandler.html):

```
@Test
public void test(){

    StringTypeHandler nullableStringTypeHandler = new StringTypeHandler();
    nullableStringTypeHandler.setNullIfEmpty(true);
    nullableStringTypeHandler.setTrim(true);

    StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
    factory.define(new StreamBuilder("pojo")
        .format("fixedlength")
        .addRecord(Pojo.class)
        .addTypeHandler(String.class, nullableStringTypeHandler)
    );


    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = factory.createUnmarshaller("pojo");

    Pojo pojo = (Pojo) unmarshaller.unmarshal("     ");
    assertNull(pojo.field);

}
```

**Update:**
As a user on the [beanio-users group suggested](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/beanio/0eM4ytgcwlc/IbXSLvuYBAAJ), one could also use `trim=true, lazy=true` on the `@Field` annotation:

```
    @Field(length = 5, trim = true, lazy = true) 
    String field;
```

Comment: trim=true lazy=true does the job +1